# Accessing error object in recent Google Chrome (43.0.2357.65 m)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I just updated to Google Chrome 43.0.2357.65 and was writing Javascript code made to log errors to the console; something like:

```
try { ...} // raise some error
catch(e) {console.log(e); ...}
```

I've used this in the past to log the Error **object** and inspect its attribute.  Now, all I see is a stack trace with no access to the Error object itself. Is this an intended behaviour?  Is there any way I can inspect the error object in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea whether this is intended behaviour, but I have been able to reproduce the difference and a quick fix is to use the `console.dir` function. `console.dir` is a great function to *always* shows up on the console as an object, even if you do something like `console.dir("a string")`.

> Displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical listing with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of child objects.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir

Comment: This seems to be working, although the warning at the top of the mozilla link is a tad worrisome.

Comment: @André You realize that all `console` functions are non-standard right? And as far as `console.dir` goes, it works in both firebug, firefox development tools, internet explorer development tools and chrome development tools... that's as standard as I need it :+ .